# Reset geometry (margin) settings after the first page

Tags: geometry

My titlepage needs to look a certain way and I would like to have the settings from the article document class being used after the title page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=25mm,
}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor}
\definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\pagecolor{azure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{swedish}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw [white,line width=10mm]
(current page.south west)
rectangle
(current page.north east)
}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace{9cm}
\color{white}\afterpage{\color{black}}

{\Huge\textbf{Example}}\vspace{6mm}

{\LARGE\textit{Independent degree project - first cycle}}

\vfill

\large\textbf{Main subject}\\
\textit{Major subject}\vspace{6mm}

\textbf{Title}\\
Header\vspace{6mm}

\textbf{Name}
\pagecolor{azure}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\color{black}
\pagebreak

\section{content here with article settings}
```

This is how it looks after the title page:
[image: bad]

And I would like it to look like this instead:
[image: good]

I tried using /restoregeometry after the title page but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You are already using tikz to overlay a white rectangle.  You could put the whole title page into a minipage inside a node.

Answer (score 1):

Make a compilable MWE in order to get helped. After all, you can use `\newgeometry{}` to get what you want. Just declare after your `\tableofcontents`. Roughly, you can use it as `\geometry{}`, a macro that you have declared at the beggining of your project.

Have a nice day!